# Anyway to provide progress from os.walk?

Tags: python

`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):` is something regularly used in python scripts.  Just wondering is there any well known way to provide progress here?  When you have a large folder structure this API can take a while?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you could, what would you display? You don't know the total numbers until you're done.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I thought python might have some API which could tell you the numbers easily and then you just log the progress.

Comment: There's no OS level API for getting the file count unfortunately, so the way you get the count is by counting the returned filenames. That goes double when you need to recurse into the subdirectories, since you don't know those until you get the file list.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - wow! seems odd. I'll leave this open for another while just in case someone thinks of something.

Comment: @dublintech the OS keeps track of the files in a tree-like structure. It only knows how to get to a file by successively asking each node in the path(a folder, essentially) for the next node until it gets to the eventual destination. There is nothing that keeps track of all files in one centralised place(or if there were, it would be something specific to a particular filesystem and not generalizable so there's no way there'd be an API for it that could work from python across filesystems). So the only way to know what all the files are is to traverse or 'walk' the tree.

Comment: You can definitely provide a progress indicator. You just can't provide a percentage indicator. In GTK, `progressbar.set_activity_mode(activity_mode)`, I think. In text mode, you can print a dot, or a spinner `|/-\|` followed by a backspace.

Answer (score 3):

The `walk` itself can't give you progress, because there's no way of knowing in advance how many entries are under some directory tree.*

However, in most programs that use `walk`, you're actually *doing something* with the files, which usually takes a whole lot longer than the implicit `stat` call. For example, grabbing my first program with `os.walk` in it, `list(os.walk(path))` takes 2.301 seconds, while my actual function (despite only operating on a small percentage of those files) takes 139.104 seconds. And I think this kind of thing is pretty typical.

So, you can first read in the entire walk (e.g., by using `list(os.walk(path))`), and then use that information to generate the progress for your real work.

In a realistic program, you'd probably want to show an "indeterminate progress bar" with a label like "Determining size..." while doing the `list(os.walk(path))`, and then replace it with a percentage progress bar with "0/12345 files" once that's done. (In fact, I'm going to go add exactly that indeterminate progress bar to my program, now that I've thought of the idea…)

(For a single-threaded interactive program, you obviously wouldn't want to just block on `list(os.walk(path))`; you might do it in a background thread with a callback to your main thread, or do one iteration of the `walk` object and `runLater` the rest each time through the event loop, etc.)

* This isn't because no filesystem or OS ever *could* do such a thing, just because they *don't*. There would obviously be some tradeoffs—for example, creating and deleting lots of tiny files would be a lot slower if you had to walk up the whole tree updating counts. Classic Mac used to solve this problem by keeping a cached count in the Finder Info… which was great, except that it meant a call that could take either 1us or 1min to return, with no way of predicting which in advance (or interrupting it) programmatically.